# How can I enter text in some web element having same attribute through webdriver(JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I enter text in some web element having same attribute through web driver (JAVA).

For example:

There are six text boxes for contact names and all are mandatory fields like contact name1, contact name2, etc. having the same attribute like id, class, etc (id-contact name).

When I am sending keys then it is filling in first text box only. Please suggest.

Comment: Share your HTML for the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Xpath for these cases, also its always advisable to share your HTML code for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actully I was not using indexing.now its working for below code.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='user-name'])[1]")).sendKeys("test1");

```
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='user-name'])[2]")).sendKeys("test2");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='user-name'])[3]")).sendKeys("test2");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='user-name'])[4]")).sendKeys("test2");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='user-name'])[5]")).sendKeys("test2");
```

Regards,
Rashid